# Type inference for higher order functions with generic return types

Tags: kotlin

The following example is perfectly legal in Kotlin 1.3.21:

```
fun <T> foo(bar: T): T = bar

val t: Int = foo(1) // No need to declare foo<Int>(1) explicitly
```

But why doesn't type inference work for higher order functions?

```
fun <T> foo() = fun(bar: T): T = bar

val t: Int = foo()(1) // Compile error: Type inference failed...
```

When using higher order functions,  Kotlin forces the call site to be:

```
val t = foo<Int>()(1)
```

Even if the return type of `foo` is specified explicitly, type inference still fails:

```
fun <T> foo(): (T) -> T = fun(bar: T): T = bar

val t: Int = foo()(1) // Compile error: Type inference failed...
```

However, when the generic type parameter is shared with the outer function, it works!

```
fun <T> foo(baz: T) = fun (bar: T): T = bar

val t: Int = foo(1)(1) // Horray! But I want to write foo()(1) instead...
```

How do I write the function `foo` so that `foo()(1)` will compile, where `bar` is a generic type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put it in simple (possibly over-simplified) terms, when you call a dynamically generated function, such as the return value of a higher-order function, it's not actually a function call, it's just syntactic sugar for the `invoke` function.

At the syntax level, Kotlin treats objects with return types like `() -> A` and `(A, B) -> C` like they are normal functions - it allows you to call them by just attaching arguments in parenthesis. This is why you can do `foo<Int>()(1)` - `foo<Int>()` returns an object of type `(Int) -> (Int)`, which is then called with `1` as an argument.

However, under the hood, these "function objects" aren't really functions, they are just plain objects with an `invoke` operator method. So for example, function objects that take 1 argument and return a value are really just instances of the special interface `Function1` which looks something like this

```
interface Function1<A, R> {
    operator fun invoke(a: A): R
}
```

Any class with `operator fun invoke` can be called like a function i.e. instead of `foo.invoke(bar, baz)` you can just call `foo(bar, baz)`. Kotlin has several built-in classes like this named `Function`, `Function1`, `Function2`, `Function<number of args>` etc. used to represent function objects. So when you call `foo<Int>()(1)`, what you are actually calling is `foo<Int>().invoke(1)`. You can confirm this by decompiling the bytecode.

[image: Decompiled Kotlin bytecode]

So what does this have to do with type inference? Well when you call `foo()(1)`, you are actually calling `foo().invoke(1)` with a little syntactic sugar, which makes it a bit easier to see why inference fails. The right hand side of the dot operator cannot be used to infer types for the left hand side, because the left hand side has to be evaluated first. So the type for `foo` has to be explicitly stated as `foo<Int>`.

Answer (score 6):

`I am not an expert on how type inference works, but the basic rule is: At the point of use the compiler must know all types in the expression being used.`

So from my understanding is that:

foo() <- using type information here

foo()(1) <- providing the information here

Looks like type inference doesn't work 'backward'

```
    val foo = foo<Int>()//create function
    val bar = foo(1)//call function
```

Comment: This would make sense, but then why does `fun <T> foo(baz: T) = fun (bar: T): T = bar` work?

Comment: Because you are providing the type through the baz parameter.
so 
val fooRet = foo(1) <- compiler knows the type
val bar = fooRet(1) <- compiler can use the type here

Comment: I thought to use a default parameter as a workaround, but unfortunately this does not work: `fun <T> foo(baz: T? = null) = fun (bar: T): T = bar` (you still need to specify `foo<Int>()(1)` at the call site).

Comment: The default parameters still need some value/type definition, it needs to know what type of 'null' is there

Answer (score 0):

Just played around with it a bit and sharing some thoughts, basically answering the last question "How do I write the function `foo` so that `foo()(1)` will compile, where `bar` is a generic type?":

A simple workaround but then you give up your higher order function (or you need to wrap it) is to have an intermediary object in place, e.g.:

```
object FooOp {
  operator fun <T> invoke(t : T) = t
}
```

with a `foo`-method similar as to follows:

```
fun foo() = FooOp
```

Of course that's not really the same, as you basically work around the first generic function. It's basically nearly the same as just having 1 function that returns the type we want and therefore it's also able to infer the type again.

An alternative to your problem could be the following. Just add another function that actually specifies the type:

```
fun <T> foo() = fun(bar: T): T = bar
@JvmName("fooInt")
fun foo() = fun(bar : Int) = bar
```

The following two will then succeed:

```
val t: Int = foo()(1)
val t2: String = foo<String>()("...")
```

but... (besides potentially needing lots of overloads) it isn't possible to define another function similar to the following:

```
@JvmName("fooString")
fun foo() = fun(bar : String) = bar
```

If you define that function it will give you an error similar as to follows:

```
Conflicting overloads: @JvmName public final fun foo(): (Int) -> Int defined in XXX, @JvmName public final fun foo(): (String) -> String defined in XXX
```

But maybe you are able to construct something with that?

Otherwise I do not have an answer to why it is infered and why it is not.